# Issue in connecting ksql with kafka of confluent version 3.3.0 in docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am setting up ksql-cli with confluent version 3.3.0 in following way

```
#zookeper
docker run -d -it \
    --net=host \
    --name=zookeeper \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181 \
    confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:3.3.0

#kafka
docker run -d \
    --net=host \
    --name=kafka \
    -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:32181 \
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092 \
    -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
    confluentinc/cp-kafka:3.3.0

#schema-registry
docker run -d \
  --net=host \
  --name=schema-registry \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=localhost:32181 \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=localhost \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://localhost:8081 \
  confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:3.3.0
```

i am running ksql-cli docker image in following manner

```
  docker run -it \
  --net=host \
  --name=ksql-cli \
  -e KSQL_CONFIG_DIR="/etc/ksql" \
  -e KSQL_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/ksql/log4j-rolling.properties" \
  -e STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=localhost:29092 \
  -e STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST=localhost \
  -e STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT=8081 \
  confluentinc/ksql-cli:0.5
```

when i am running `ksql-cli` by going in bash of container in folowing way

```
docker exec -it ksql-cli bash
```

and running `ksql-cli` in following way:

```
./usr/bin/ksql-cli local
```

It is giving me following error:

> Initializing KSQL...
>
> Could not fetch broker information. KSQL cannot initialize AdminCLient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the ksql-cli attempts to connect to the Kafka brokers on localhost:9092. It looks like your setup is using a different port, so you'll need to provide this on the command line, e.g.

`./usr/bin/ksql-cli local --bootstrap-server localhost:32181`

You'll probably also need to specify the schema registry port, so you may want to use a properties file, e.g. :

`./usr/bin/ksql-cli local --properties-file ./ksql.properties`

Where ksql.properties has:

`bootstrap.servers=localhost:29092
schema.registry.url=localhost:8081`

Or provide both on the command line:

`./usr/bin/ksql-cli local \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 \
  --schema.registry.url http://localhost:8081`

Note, from KSQL version 4.1 onwards the commands and properties change name.  `ksql-cli` becomes just `ksql`. The `local` mode disappears - you'll need to run a ksql-server node or two explicitly. `--property-file` becomes `--config-file` and `schema.registry.url` becomes `ksql.schema.registry.url`.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. The issue is not on the ksql-client, but on the ksql-server which refuses to boot up. Not clear how/ why supplying parameters to the client can help when the ksql server itself isnt up.